# Left-over pixels to the right - unnecessary scroll bar

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I've been trying to figure out a little mystery now for a while, but I just can't seem to locate the problem. [This Wordpress blog](http://www.matogvinnett.no/), which I'm managing, has this really annoying left-over pixels on the right which makes the scroll-bar appear unnecessarily.

Does anyone know what's causing this, and/or how to fix it? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a border around the ul#suckerfishnav - pull it from the left and right sides as it adds 2px to your layout.